# Python Geoserver gsconfig create resource from Postgis store table

Tags: python, geoserver, postgis-2.0

I've working Workspace and PostGIS store in GeoServer. I would like to use python and [gsconfig](https://github.com/boundlessgeo/gsconfig) to create new resource/new layer from existing PostGIS table, with:

computing bbox,
adding abstract,
adding keywords,
setting style,
other attributes.

Is it doable with gsconfig? Could you provide any examples?
The same goes with removing resources (layers).

Answer (score 6):

Bit late to the party, but I'll answer anyway

**1. Connect to GeoServer**

```
cat = Catalog('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest')
```

**2. Create a Workspace**

```
ws = cat.create_workspace('newWorkspaceName','newWorkspaceUri')
```

**3. Create PostGIS store**

```
ds = cat.create_datastore(newDatastoreName,newWorkspaceName)

ds.connection_parameters.update(host='localhost', port='5432', database='postgis', user='postgres', passwd='password', dbtype='postgis', schema='postgis')

cat.save(ds)
```

**4. Add Layer**

```
ft = cat.publish_featuretype('newLayerName', ds, 'EPSG:4326', srs='EPSG:4326')

cat.save(ft)
```

Answer (score 3):

We use it within the GeoNode project.
Here is the code we use to create a layer:
https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/blob/master/geonode/layers/utils.py#L274

Comment: Ok, your code is fine, however, I do not find answer in it.
As far as I understand, you always upload shapefile using _create_db_featurestore and You are doing:
cat.add_data_to_store(ds, name, data,
                              overwrite=overwrite,
                              charset=charset)
        return ds, cat.get_resource(name, store=ds)


and after add_data_to_store you have a 'resource'.

In my case, I already have working store and data upload in different process. However, I do not know how to create resource/layer out of existing table in PostGIS.