# Generating WFS, WMS by scripting?

Tags: geoserver, wms, wfs

I want to generate WFS and WMS from a PostGIS database. To do this I want to make a script with Python (or with another language) to store my shapefile on GeoServer and then deploy services automatically.

Is there any good approach to follow?

[OWSlib](https://geopython.github.io/OWSLib/#wfs) could be one?

And what about [geoscripting](http://pt.slideshare.net/JaredErickson/scripting-geoserver?next_slideshow=1)?

Point of situation:
I have made a script for creating shapefiles and generate metadata so the next step is to build a script that post my datasets into GeoServer to generate services. The number of datasets are constantly growing because is periodic data, and I will assume that this upload script simply will be executed occasionally by user interaction or eventually a daemon could be configured.

The data will be provided from different database, converted into specific datasets(shapefile) and will feed a GeoServer (or MapServer), service.

Is there any script that already make this interaction, to upload shapefiles from a specific directory into GeoServer?

Comment: There is the [Rest API](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/) in GeoServer -- not sure if that is what you meant.

Comment: A few more details in the question please: how many shapefiles? How often do they change? What formats do you want to publish the layers out in? Do you really need postgis, or would a straight shapefile data source be enough? (hint - tell us more about the data and your needs!) Scripting is the solution, but for more details on that, you need to help us with the problem.

Comment: BradHands, thanks for your suggestion i added to question the scenario to answer to your questions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [geoconfig](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gsconfig) python module:

> gsconfig is a python library for manipulating a GeoServer instance via
>   the GeoServer RESTConfig API.

[Documentation](http://boundlessgeo.github.io/gsconfig/index.html)

Here is a similar Q/A that may help too:

[Python Geoserver gsconfig create resource from Postgis store table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84031/python-geoserver-gsconfig-create-resource-from-postgis-store-table)